# A inequality concerns with eigenvalue of a symmetric and positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

How to prove the statement: Let $A$ be a symmetric and positive definite matrix of order $n$. Suppose that $\lambda_{\min}\ge \lambda_0>0$, where $\lambda_{\min}$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $A$. Prove that
$$\left\| {{A^{ - 1}}v} \right\| \leqslant \frac{1}{{{\lambda _0}}}\left\| v \right\|,\forall v\in\mathbb{R}^n,$$
where $||.||$ denotes the Euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $\lambda_{min} \ge \lambda_0 >0$, then

$$(*)\ \ \ \ \|A w\| \ge \lambda _0 \|w\| $$

for all $w$. Putting $w = A^{-1} v$ gives your result.

**Remark** To see why $(*)$ is true, note that as $A$ is symmetric, there is an orthonormal basis $e_1, \cdots e_n$ so that $A e_i = \lambda _i e_n$. Then for any $w\in \mathbb R^n$, write $w= w_1 e_1 + \cdots + w_n e_n$. Then

$$\begin{split}
\|A w\| &= \|\lambda_1 w_1 e_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n w_n e_n \|\\
&= \|\lambda_1 w_1 e_1\| + \cdots + \|\lambda_n w_n e_n \| \ \ \ \ \text{(as the basis is orthgonal)} \\
&= \lambda_1 \| w_1 e_1 \| + \cdots \lambda_n \|w_n e_n\| \\
&\ge \lambda_{0} ( \| w_1 e_1\| + \cdots \|w_n e_n\|) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{(as }\lambda_i \ge \lambda_0)\\
&= \lambda_0 \|w\|.
\end{split}$$

Comment: Can you explain why we have $||Aw||\ge \lambda_0 ||w||$?

Comment: @User3101 Please see the edit.

Comment: Now your answer becomes clear with me. Thank you very much.